# filtering a stream changes its wildcard bounds?

Tags: java, generics, java-stream, unbounded-wildcard

the below method compiles without problems:

```java
static Stream<Optional<? extends Number>> getNumbers(Stream<Number> numbers) {
    return numbers.map(Optional::of);
}
```

yet if I add a simple filtering to it like this:

```java
static Stream<Optional<? extends Number>> getNumbers2(Stream<Number> numbers) {
    return numbers.map(Optional::of).filter(number -> true);
}
```

it generates the following error:

> incompatible types:
> java.util.stream.Stream<java.util.Optional<java.lang.Number>> cannot be converted to
> java.util.stream.Stream<java.util.Optional<? extends java.lang.Number>>

tested on openJdk-11 and openJdk-17.

I'd expect them both to do the same (either both compile ok or both generate the same compilation error), so I'm really puzzled by this: what is the general rule here that explains why the 1st method compiles ok yet the 2nd does not?
Thanks!

Comment: Stream<? extends Optional<? extends Number>> seems to do the trick, but I wonder why

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compatibility with the return type `Stream<Optional<? extends Number>>` in the first case is not obtained by virtue of `numbers.map(Optional::of)` returning a `Stream<Optional<? extends Number>>` on its own; it's the compiler inferring the return type of `numbers.map(...)` due to  it being a generic method:

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper);
```

while `Stream.filter()` is not:

```
Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate);
```

Therefore, in the first case the compiler can take into account the return statement's context (`getNumbers`'s type) when inferring type of `numbers.map(...)`.
Compiler cannot do the same for `numbers.map(...)` in the second case,  as there are subsequent chained calls, that may further change the type, so it would be very hard to guess what the right inferring should be at this stage. As a result, the most specific possible type is assumed for `numbers.map(...)` (`Stream<Optional<Number>>`) and further carried on by `filter(...)`.

As a different example to illustrate that, please figure out why both of these compile (`List.of()` is the same code, after all):

```
static List<String> stringList() {
    return List.of();
}
static List<Integer> intList() {
    return List.of();
}
```

Now, why does this fail:

```
static List<String> stringList() {
    return List.of().subList(0, 0);
}
```

That's because `List.subList(...)` does not infer the returned list's `E` type in context (i.e., the method is not generic), it carries the `List` instance's `E` type, which, with `List.of()` in that case gets defaulted to `Object` (yes, when you have `return List.of();`, return type inference kicks in, forcing the compiler to figure out that the intent is to make `E` match `String`, the type argument in the method's return type). *Please note that this gets more complex than that, there are corners where inference doesn't work as wished/expected.*

---

**Short answer**: `return numbers.map(Optional::of)` takes advantage of type inference as `map()` is generic, and `filter()` does not, expecting the `E` of `Stream<E>` to be carried. And with `numbers.map(Optional::of)`, `E` is `Optional<Number>`, not `Optional<? extends Number>`, and `filter` carries that.

Comment: I still don't understand what prevents the compiler in the second case to do a type analysis of `numbers.map(...)` part first, take advantage of type inference as you explained and **then** apply `filter(...)` to it...

Comment: ahh, I think I get it: in case of partial type analysis, it lacks the context what to infer it to (there may be other mappings later that change type back and forth, so it would be very hard for compiler to guess what the right inference should be at this stage).

Comment: @morgwai Spot on. The compiler doesn't carry inferred types when there are chained methods afterwards. Well, it pretty much doesn't do type inference in that case.